# Access the value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, jsx

code

```
props.thumbnails.forEach(value=>{
        console.log(value.photo.thumbnail_url);
    })
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail_url' of undefined
```

When I try

```
props.thumbnails.forEach(value=>{
        console.log(value.photo);
    })
```

response

```
{owner: 7, thumbnail_url: "images/CACHE/images/barack_obama-2/888e0a85a1c0244831ec95e6a6716347.jpg", created_at: "2018-02-07"}
{owner: 7, thumbnail_url: "images/CACHE/images/170622210800-barack-obama-file-full-169/2560197d333c86930614c29755ef5237.jpg", created_at: "2018-02-07"}
```

I am trying to get thumbnail_url from the photo which is inside the array. But i can't achieve this. Can someone help me with this?

update:
When I try this

```
console.log(props.thumbnails[0].photo)
```

result

```
{owner: 7, thumbnail_url: "images/CACHE/images/barack_obama-2/888e0a85a1c0244831ec95e6a6716347.jpg", created_at: "2018-02-07"}
```

update 2: 
code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(props.thumbnails))
```

result

```
[{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/barack_obama-2/888e0a85a1c0244831ec95e6a6716347.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/170622210800-barack-obama-file-full-169/2560197d333c86930614c29755ef5237.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/barack_obama-2_4xWOj4h/8ff56440afd36924b5c4f4edc34e0abf.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/bck/3dc4db87dc07448888be58dc34ed7be0.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/barack_obama-2_RtQE7Dh/8b308f5d48591b1cd14141a68ddd0aa5.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/obama_rEmzr6f/5c7e1a1698c28f9d03a3c3f0f28b430d.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":7,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/President_Barack_Obama_mpU4fZP/1712b21906092dd6931d76604f20874a.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"},{"photo":{"owner":6,"thumbnail_url":"images/CACHE/images/obama_d7uqGPL/b75e7e2bca6c3189303c307aed640b96.jpg","created_at":"2018-02-07"},"tag":"6"}]
```

Comment: Already tried value.photo["thumbnail_url"] ?

Comment: ok.let me try that way

Comment: are you sure you have the data on the initial render?

Comment: they are the same `value.photos.thumbnail_url` and `value.photos["thumbnail_url"]`. Wont make a difference. The fact that you have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail_url' of undefined` means that `value.photos` is undefined when you're trying to read it

Comment: I think `value` might be a reserved keyword in JS, so change it to `x` or something and see if that works.

Comment: value.photo["thumbnail_url"]  not working

Comment: can you add a dump of console.log(props.thumbnails) to your question

Comment: Weird. But @Sagivb.g might be right, check if photo is defined before logging the data.

Comment: can you show us a `jsfiddle` ?

Comment: but when i log ` props.thumbnails.forEach(value=>{
        console.log(value.photo);
    }) ` way ti gives the above output is the details

Comment: @ilovecse you're doing *something* different because the error says that is undefined. Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: just a guess but i think when you do `console.log(value.photo)` you print `undefined` before you print the actual data.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ryueq8qj/   jsfiddle link with full code

Comment: line number 273

Comment: @developer I get the data when i dump  console.log(props.thumbnails) .  That works

Comment: Your fiddle errors with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Please read [mcve]

Comment: I appreciate that you think you have dumped everything, but I think you need step back and look at console.log(props.thumbnails) or console.log(props) as I think there is a trailing undef in your array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your `jsfiddle` code. you've initialized `props.thumbnails` as the wrong format. check out `line 23`. this is what comes to the iteration of `props.thumbnails` at the initial call. that's why you're getting the error *undefined*.

change the code from

```
sharedThumbs: [{ thumbnail_url: '' }],
```

to

```
sharedThumbs: [{ photo:{ owner:0, thumbnail_url: '' } }],
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `foreach` use `props.thumbnails.map(thumbail => {})`;

```
props.thumbnails.map(thumbnail => console.log(thumbnail));
```

Comment: How would this be any different?

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: `map` is used to return a new array. If you're not interested in return value, use `forEach` instead.